# view to controller data passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

when i select dropdown selected dropdown value is not come in controller action method. selected value is binding in ajax but not bind in controller action method
[see our page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzrFA.png)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label semibold control-label">Generic</label> 
      @Html.DropDownList("MasterGenericID", null, "--- Select Generic ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

```js
$('#btnsearch').click(function() {
  var genericID = $('#MasterGenericID').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Action("ProductMasterController", "ProductMasterview")",
    data: JSON.stringify(GenericID),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // if (response.id > 0)
      alert("test" + data.GenericID);
    },
    async: true // make it true if you want to make an async call.
  });
});
```

```csharp
public ActionResult ProductMasterview(string GenericID)
  if (Convert.ToInt32(GenericID) > 0) 
  {
    return View(dPMSP.GetAllProductsUsingGenericID(GenericID));
  } 
  else 
  {
    Generic_Bind();
    Therapeutic_Bind();
    SubTherapeutic_Bind();
    Formulation_Bind();
    return View(dPMSP.GetAllProducts());
  }
}
```

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTnbR.png)

Thanks

Comment: Your action definition is missing the opening `{`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a bunch of issues.

Take a look at this line

```
data: JSON.stringify(GenericID),
```

You are using a variable `GenericID`, but it is not defined anywhere. Remember **javascript is case sensitive**. So make sure you are using the correct case.

Now take a look at this line

```
url: '@Url.Action("ProductMasterController", "ProductMasterview")',
```

You are using the `Url.Action` helper method incorrectly. If you are using the overload which takes 2 parameters ,the first parameter should be action name and the second should be controller name. Also you do not need the `Controller` suffix. So it should be something like

```
url: "@Url.Action("ProductMasterview", "ProductMaster")",
```

Another issue i noticed is, you are specifying the dataType property of your ajax call as `json`. The `$.ajax` method uses this property value to parse the data coming from the server. Here you are telling `$.ajax` that you are expecting JSON response from the server. But your action method is returning a view result , which is HTML/Plain text, not JSON. So your code will not work as expected.

I also see that you are making a POST call, but your action method is not decorated with HttpPost attribute. So your ajax call will not hit the action method. Also it is unclear from your question what type of data you want to return.(JSON / View result-HTML).

If you are returning a view result (html markup), you should be returning a partial view result so that you can use that to update some part of your DOM. 
There is no point in making an ajax call, if you are returning the entire view (i get a feeling that you are trying to do so when i see the 4 method calls in your `else` part in your action method code).

Also use the correct data type. If you are passing a numeric value, use a numeric type (`int` or `long`) instead of using `string` as param and doing a conversion later. Keep in mind that the `Convert.ToInt32` can throw an exception when the value you are passing to it cannot be safely converted to an int (ex :`12abc`).

Use `int` as the parameter type.

```
public ActionResult ProductMasterview(int genericId)
{
    // some other logic you want to do .
    return PartialView(dPMSP.GetAllProductsUsingGenericID(genericId));
}
```

You should update the `GetAllProductsUsingGenericID` method to also take int type, not string.

Now at your client side, you can pass the selected option value in the data property. Since your action method is not decorated with HttpPost attribute, simply use GET (the default type for `$.ajax`). Also send the selected option value in a js object with the key matching to your action method parameter name.

```
$('#btnsearch').click(function() {
    var id = $('#MasterGenericID').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ProductMasterview", "ProductMaster")",
        data: { genericId: id }  
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log('Received response from server');
        console.log(response);
        // If you want to update the DOM with the response
        // Ex : $("#SomeDomElementId").html(response);
    }).fail(function(x, a, e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
```

If you want to return JSON from your action method, that is fine. You do not need to necessarily specify the `dataType` property as jQuery will try to intelligently guess it based on the response headers.

Comment: genericID came in controller action method but at the same time there perform two operation  one is if condition another one if else condition  also perform there showing else condition only

Answer (score 0):

You are directly passing value to ajax call instead you should pass an object with GenericID property

Example-

```
    $('#btnsearch').click(function () {
    var value = $('#MasterGenericID').val();

    var data = {
        GenericID: value
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("ProductMasterview", "ProductMaster")",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // if (response.id > 0)
            alert("test" + data.GenericID);
        },
        async: true // make it true if you want to make an async call.
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no need to use `JSON.stringify()` just use `data: data` and delete the `contentType` option. But this still throws an exception because the method returns html, not json = delete the `dataType` option or specify `dataType: 'html'`  (and `async` is `true` by default)

Answer (score 0):

The js should be like

```
$('#btnsearch').click(function() {
  var genericID = $('#MasterGenericID').val();
  var postData={
               GenericID:genericID
               };
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("ProductMasterController", "ProductMasterview")',
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // if (response.id > 0)
      alert("test" + data.GenericID);
    },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert('Failed to delete');
                                }
  });
});
```

And The C# code should look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductMasterview(string GenericID)
{
  if (Convert.ToInt32(GenericID) > 0) 
  {

    //return View(dPMSP.GetAllProductsUsingGenericID(GenericID));
    //you can return only the genericId as you expect it at ajax success
    return Json(new { GenericID = yourGenericId});
  } 
  else 
  {
    Generic_Bind();
    Therapeutic_Bind();
    SubTherapeutic_Bind();
    Formulation_Bind();
    //return View(dPMSP.GetAllProducts());
    //you can return only the genericId as you expect it at ajax success

    return Json(new { GenericID = yourGenericId});
  }
}
```